# Error when compiling chapters into main document

Tags: errors, thesis, compilation-error

For my thesis, I want to compile various tex docs as chapters. Unfortunately, when trying to link the various chapters, I receive the following error:

> File: chapter_1/tex/chapter1 "!Missing number, treated as zero.}\section{introduction}
> File: chapter_1/tex/chapter1
> "!Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).}\section{introduction}

Below a snippet of my LaTex code:

**The main document i.e. the compiler of the various chapters:**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass
[
    paper=a4, % choose page size e.g. a4 or b5 (common booklet size)
    fontsize=12pt,
    headings=big,
    parskip, %indent at paragrafs?
    numbers=noendperiod, % 2.3.1 vs 2.3.1. (no dot after the last chapter number)
    twoside=true, %choose two sided for a booklet style, semi leaves the margings the same
    headinclude,
    pagesize,
    appendixprefix=false,
    headsepline,
    toc=bibliography, % Bibliography appears in Table of Contents (without a number)
    version=last % Use latest version of the KOMA-Script
]{Thesis_Template}

% Add the configuration and packages
\input{definitions/configuration}
\input{definitions/packages_commands}
\input{definitions/hyphenation}

% ad hoc settings
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

%import packages that need to be imported separately
\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

%toggle for footnotes to continue over the chapters
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\flipbindingmargins

% ad hoc spacing for sections
\setlength\parskip{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}{1em plus 0em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}{.6em plus 0em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}{.6em plus 0em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\headerpage

%% Startmain content
\mainmatter
\chapter[Chapter 1]{Chapter 1 long title} \label{chapt 1}
%import actual chapter tex
\import{chapter_1/tex/}{chapter1}   

\end{document}
```

**An exemplary code of a chapter:**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{standalone} \standalonetrue %to allow it to be part of thesis
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
%Settings
\tolerance=2000
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue
  }

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

%sections setup
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{\hyperlink{toc}{{\black{#1}}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{\hyperlink{toc}{\it{\black{#1}}}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\thesubsubsection.}{.5em}{\it{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{11pt}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\ifstandalone

\title{\sc{Title}
\unskip\thanks{Thanks to ...}
}
\author{John Doe}
 }

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\vspace{-1.5em}

%%%%%%% ABSTRACT %%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\parbox[t]{.9\textwidth}{ 
\begin{small}
\singlespacing
Abstract text here.

\clearpage

\doublespacing
\fi

%%%%%%% Introduction %%%%%%%

\section{Introduction}
Introduction text here

\end{document}
```

I am using TeX Maker. I also made sure that all packages are up to date.

I read online in other posts that it might have something to do with the ***titlesec*** package but could not figure out a solution.

Many thanks for your support!

Comment: I'm not sure you should be using `\import` here, probably more like the features from the `standalone` package.

Answer (score 1):

The `\import` command is based on the `\input` command, which basically pastes the file pointed to right at the spot of the `\input`/`\import`. That includes `\documentclass` and the rest of your preamble. Of course, that's not going to work!

Instead, you should use the `subfiles` package. See [How to bring existing LaTeX files as chapters of thesis appendix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598037/242407)

I'm not entirely sure this is what's going on here, because I get the more descriptive error `Can be used only in preamble`. But then, I'm using a very clean minimal document, and with more configurations going on, things mix up easier.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Unfortunatley, it still did not work. The "interesting" thing is when I do not use the "\section" command, the compilation into the master doc works. The error only appears when using "\section" (both with mine and your suggested approach)

Comment: @Neicooo Is it possible for you to comment out the `titlesec` stuff, see if things work then?

Comment: Not sure if I got you there, but do you mean the thread related to that topic that I found? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302111/multiple-missing-number-treated-as-zero-and-illegal-unit-of-measure-pt-insert

Comment: Commenting out is placing a percent sign (`%`) at the start of code lines. These will be seen as 'comments' by LaTeX, and hence be ignored. It's as if you deleted those lines from your code, except you can sort of keep them.

Comment: @Neicooo `titlesec` is mostly aesthetics. Hence, I would think you can just disable those lines in the configurations, and see if things work then. It tells us whether the problem lies at `titlesec`, as you were conjecturing, or whether it's something else

Comment: LaTeX errors are notoriously indescriptive. `Missing number, treated as zero.` can be caused by almost everything. The help provided at the question you linked is very specific to his case. Might not be yours

Comment: Yes it worked when %\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}{1em plus 0em}
%\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}{.6em plus 0em}
%\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1em plus 0em minus 0.1em}{.6em plus 0em}

Comment: Is there another way to reproduce those aesthetics without titlesec?

Comment: Hm, well perhaps there is indeed a compatibility question, like the post you linked too. You use many packages, and base your MWE on a class Thesis_Template which is non-standard. Is it based on `scrbook`, like in the post you linked? You could either try the alternatives in the question you linked, or copy your document and strip it to get the smallest document which can still produce the problem. One which other people, like me, can compile for themselves as well